# Delete all (hourly) day entries per row based on a daily table in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a `datetime64[ns]` object which has the format, so there I have data per hourly base:

```
Datum                    Values
2020-01-01 00:00:00      1
2020-01-01 01:00:00      10
....
2020-02-28 00:00:00     5
2020-03-01 00:00:00     4
```

and another table with closing days, also in a `datetime64[ns]` column with the format, so there I only have a dayformat:

```
Dates
2020-02-28
2020-02-29
....
```

How can I delete all days in the first dataframe df, which occure in the second dataframe Dates? So that df is:

```
2020-01-01 00:00:00      1
2020-01-01 01:00:00      10
....
2020-03-01 00:00:00      4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandaspydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) for set `time`s to `0`, so possible filter by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with inverted mask in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df['Datum'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datum'])
df1['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Dates'])

df = df[~df['Datum'].dt.floor('d').isin(df1['Dates'])]
print (df)
                Datum  Values
0 2020-01-01 00:00:00       1
1 2020-01-01 01:00:00      10
3 2020-03-01 00:00:00       4
```

EDIT: For flag column convert mask to integers by [`Series.view`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.view.html) or [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['flag'] = df['Datum'].dt.floor('d').isin(df1['Dates']).view('i1')
#alternative
#df['flag'] = df['Datum'].dt.floor('d').isin(df1['Dates']).astype('int')
print (df)
                Datum  Values  flag
0 2020-01-01 00:00:00       1     0
1 2020-01-01 01:00:00      10     0
2 2020-02-28 00:00:00       5     1
3 2020-03-01 00:00:00       4     0
```

Comment: thx, how can I add a column with 0 (not the dropping dates) and 1 (dropping dates) to the dataframe df, so that I have a marker instead of deleting the rows?

Answer (score 1):

Putting you aded comment into consideration

```
string of the Dates in df1
c="|".join(df1.Dates.values)
c
```

Coerce Datum to datetime

```
df['Datum']=pd.to_datetime(df['Datum'])
df.dtypes
```

Extract Datum as Dates ,dtype string

```
df.set_index(df['Datum'],inplace=True)
df['Dates']=df.index.date.astype(str)
```

Boolean select date ins in both

```
m=df.Dates.str.contains(c)
m
```

Mark inclusive dates as 0 and exclusive as 1

```
df['drop']=np.where(m,0,1)
df
```

Drop unwanted rows

```
df.reset_index(drop=True).drop(columns=['Dates'])
```

Outcome

[image]